# How to get information from custom fields within SuperTags pulled from Batchbook CRM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the batchbook ruby gem to build a simple listing page pulling various fields out of my batchbook crm. If I pull all the attributes for a given company, I end up with something like this:

```
{"id"=>13, "name"=>"John Deer", "notes"=>nil, "small_image"=>nil, "large_image"=>nil, "tags"=>[#<BatchBook::Tag:0x00000001df6438 @attributes={"id"=>"1002", "name"=>"portfolio", "supertag"=>"true", "fields"=>#<BatchBook::Tag::Fields:0x00000001dee5a8 @attributes={"logo"=>"img/fr-logo-button-sm.png", "description"=>"We make tractors."}, @prefix_options={}>}, @prefix_options={}>], "locations"=>[#<BatchBook::Location:0x00000001dea048 @attributes={"id"=>14, "label"=>"main", "primary"=>true, "email"=>"***@johndeer.com", "website"=>"http://johndeer.com", "phone"=>nil, "cell"=>nil, "fax"=>nil, "street_1"=>nil, "street_2"=>nil, "city"=>nil, "state"=>nil, "postal_code"=>nil, "country"=>nil}, @prefix_options={}>], "mega_comments"=>[], "created_at"=>"Thu Jun 02 22:32:16 UTC 2011", "updated_at"=>"Thu Jun 02 22:40:03 UTC 2011"}
```

How can I parse this to pull just the "logo" or just the "description" from within my "portfolio" SuperTag?

Maybe it's simpler to use just the `@company.supertag` object, which gives me this:

```
[{"id"=>15, "name"=>"portfolio", "fields"=>{"logo"=>"img/fr-logo-button-sm.png", "description"=>"We make tractors."}}]
```

but again, how can I pull out the individual fields "logo" or "description"?

I feel like this should be a simple process, and maybe I'm either struggling with the syntax or making it more complicated than it needs to be, but could you please help me out?

Comment: The first string came from calling the attributes method on my company object from the batchbook gem. Looks like I just got confused trying to mix the hash and array in the right order. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not that I know of. All I did was store a company object as @company, then called @company.attributes, trying to see what all was available. (looks like I have to make 2 separate http requests to get my supertag info, with how batchbook's API is set up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your first hash-like string is all about so we'll look at the `@company.supertag` output value:

```
[
    {
        "id"     => 15,
        "name"   => "portfolio",
        "fields" => {
            "logo"        => "img/fr-logo-button-sm.png",
            "description" => "We make tractors."
        }
    }
]
```

I took the liberty of reformatting it into something readable. The square brackets on the outside indicate that it is an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html), the braces come in at the next level so the Array contains a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html). Both Array and Hash use `[]` to access their elements so, if the whole data structure is in `a` and we remember that an Array is indexed starting at 0, we start with this:

```
a[0]['fields']
```

And that gives us this inner hash:

```
"fields" => {
    "logo"        => "img/fr-logo-button-sm.png",
    "description" => "We make tractors."
}
```

And taking it one step further:

```
logo = a[0]['fields']['logo']
desc = a[0]['fields']['description']
```